# Custom height for UITableViewCell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I use the following:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] * 20;
}
```

I have a dynamically populated list and when I use the above, it takes all of my `table view cells` and only displays one of them.

Not sure why?

This is a MySQL populated list and I never know how many cells there will be.  But for testing purposes lets say 2.

Comment: How many rows are there in each section?

Comment: Its dynamically populated from a MySQL database

Comment: So I never know, but for testing purposes, 2.

Comment: Well, the first row is number `0`, so it will never appear (height = `0 * 20` == `0`). If you just have one section with 2 rows then you will just see one item...

Comment: Just to be clear: do you know that this method is expected to return a relative height, not related to its x,y location on the screen?

Comment: @bneely I understand I am simply trying to define a height for all of the cells being populated.

Comment: @wain what do you mean?

Comment: Try `([indexPath row] + 1) * 20` and this will become clear.

Comment: @bneely okay so its confusing to me because the bottom cell is way bigger than the top cell

Comment: @DavidBiga That's correct. This is because tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: returns a relative height, not a height coordinate in the superview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row of every section is number 0, so it will never appear (height = `0 * 20` == `0`). If you just have one section with 2 rows then you will just see one item. If you have 2 sections, each with 2 rows then you will see 2 rows (the second row in each section). If all of your sections have only 1 row then you will never see anything.

Change `return [indexPath row] * 20;` to `return 50;` and see what happens.

Then, change to:

```
NSLog(@"Multiply %d by 0, result is %d", [indexPath row], [indexPath row] * 20);
return [indexPath row] * 20;
```

Comment: Wain is it possible to define a width for a cell?

Comment: A cell is effectively a static width. You change the `x` position and `width` of the subviews you add to the cell. Or set the indentation level for the cell (`tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: What I am trying to also do is, think of a facebook post on the IPhone how the post have a smaller width and are centered in the center of the screen and I am trying to mimic that same action.

Comment: You mean each cell has a little border around the edge of it? Look at using a resizable image as the background for the cell.

Comment: Wain ya, so quick question for you.....UIWebView vs the UITableView.  I am working on an app that will give a news feed type feel similar to facebook and same with how the post are styled.  Which is better solution to move by?

Comment: Personal choice. I would use `UITableView`.

Comment: That what I was thinking to because I will need to use the camera and everything.  Do you know any intenseive UITableView styling's tutorials or such?

Comment: It's old: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html